# how to get a .shp map R

Tags: r, maps, shapefile

I am trying to replicate [this tutorial](http://aasa.ut.ee/Rspatial/05_session.html) with my data for South Africa.

How can I get a .shp file of South Africa? I need a simple contour, nothing extra.

I am a complete novice in geo data analysis, thanks.

Comment: https://africaopendata.org/group/south-africa?res_format=SHP

Answer (score 1):

One of the best sources of geodata is at the website:

https://gadm.org/data.html

This website has geodata for every country and the data is well organized.  GADM provides maps and spatial data for all countries and their sub-divisions.  For each country, there is the choice of the type of geodata you want.  The three commonly used geodata types are:

- shape file
- sf
- sp

The sf and the sp data types are subdivided and classified into different levels of detail.

- gsdm36_0 - provides the outline of the selected country.
- gsdm36_1  - provides the outline of the country and the states.
- gsdm36_2  - provides the detail the country, states, and the counties.